# Laravel "No scheduled commands are ready to run."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, schedule

I've set up the following Laravel commands on the `App\Console\Kernel`:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command('command:daily-reset')->daily();
    $schedule->command('command:monthly-reset')->monthly();
}
```

Then, on my server, I've set up a cron job to run once per day (at 00:00).

```
0 0 * * * php /home/privates/public_html/staging/current/artisan schedule:run
```

My cron job is running successfully each night, but the logs simply say: "No scheduled commands are ready to run."

What am I doing wrong? I would expect my `daily` command to run each night.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try running command manually?

Run `php artisan` and see if your commands have registered.

If you have registered your commands you should see `command:daily-reset` and `command:monthly-reset` under the list of available artisan commands.

If you don't see them there go ahead and register your commands by adding it to `commands` property available in `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\YourFirstCommand',
    'App\Console\Commands\YourSecondCommand'
];
```

Change crontab entry to

`* * * * * php /home/privates/public_html/staging/current/artisan schedule:run`

Comment: Yes, I've tried running both commands manually and they are working fine. They've already been added to the `$commands` array. All functionality seems to be working as expected  - the only problem is the cron isn't triggering them to run, just displaying the message shown in my question. Thanks

Comment: Change crontab entry to `* * * * * php /home/privates/public_html/staging/current/artisan schedule:run`.

Comment: I changed it to run every minute and it appears to be working. Seems stupidly inefficient to have to run it every minute to accomplish something once a day - but that's a problem for another day. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Commands runs everyMinute, but everyFiveMinutes dont. :/

Comment: In addition to this, cronjobs run every minute. If nothing is scheduled it gives this message.

Answer (score 40):

When you run

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

in the server, where your project is stored, you could see all of your commands running with output, looking like this:

```
"Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' cache:update > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &"
```

but only if the current time is the exact one, for which the command is scheduled. Otherwise you are going to see this output:

```
"No scheduled commands are ready to run."
```

For example, if you schedule the command for every five minutes and run the command in 09:07 o'clock you will see that there are no scheduled commands, but if you run it in 09:10 you will see your command running.

In this way you can just schedule your command to run every 5 min just for debugging purposes:

```
$schedule->command('command:daily-reset')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

then observe if there is any error while running and eventually fix it. By me the problem was that I haven't installed GuzzleHttp (shame), so the fix was just running this in the terminal:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I run my cron scripts on Rackspace/LiquidWeb and they are notorious for running a few minutes late. My scheduler was set to `everyTenMinutes()` but because RS was running the scripts two to three minutes after the exact ten minute mark, the scheduler tasks would not run. My solution was to use `everyMinute()` since that degree of frequency is okay for me.

Answer (score 21):

I realized that the problem for me was the below chained method:

```
->withoutOverlapping()
```

Once I removed that method, my commands started running and being found by the daemon process.

I think there might be a bug with the method, but my project for now can take a bit overlapping so it's cool.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39804140/1128918) gives a clue on why `withoutOverlapping` could not be working in your case. I had a similar issue but I wanted to keep the overlapping check in place. In my case, an instance reboot caused the issue.

Comment: One more thought: I had no schedule file in `storage/framework` dir. However, running `php artisan cache:clear` did the trick.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. The flag set by `withoutOverlapping` expires in 24 hours (!) by default. In my case, it made much more sense to use it like `->withoutOverlapping(5)`, which states the flag should expire in 5 minutes instead.

Answer (score 14):

The Laravel scheduled commands are based in the timezone that you have configured in your app/config/app.php file (laravel 5.1):

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'America/Bogota',
```

So if you create a command and register it to run as a scheduled task with:

```
$schedule->command('command:daily-reset')->daily();
```

it will run every day at 00:00 OF THE TIMEZONE SPECIFIED (in this case America/Bogota)

The same thing applies if you specify a time to run the task:

```
$schedule->command('command:daily-reset')->daily()->at('02:30');
```

This will run at 02:30 am in America/Bogota local time.

Comment: On your last bit of code, I believe it is not chained, but rather a single method, dailyAt()

Comment: nice. this is my problem. trust this guy.

Answer (score 8):

NB: This is not answer for this question, but a clue for anyone debugging with `php artisan schedule:run` manually. Hope it saves someone a few minutes of headache.

Check if the scheduled task can run immediately. You can use the `exec` method for that.

```
<?php

//...

protected function schedule (Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->exec("php artisan your:command");
}
```

The reason for this is that, you might be scheduling the task to run at a certain time and if that time isn't due yet, it will output:

```bash
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it not exit before all the scheduled tasks are done? Or is there a way to test the entries made in Kernel.php will run successfully before deploying it in production?

Comment: @sabertooth1990 I didn't get the first part of the question: making it exit. But for testing, I always try to clone my production environment as much as possible locally - or if that's not possible, on a staging environment - so I also have a cron running the schedules locally too.

Comment: when I run `php artisan your:command` from console it works. but when I put something like
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
        $schedule->command('my:command')
                 ->dailyAt('13:40')
                 ->withoutOverlapping();
    }
it doesn't get scheduled and done even if I wait a whole day.

Comment: Can you verify that the cron that runs `artisan schedule:run` is running?

List all active crons using: `crontab -l`

if it isn't part of the list - take note of the */path/to/artisan* - add the following line to your `crontab -e`  `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Every command was **correctly registered** but I always received the **“No scheduled commands are ready to run.”** message. The problem was that the website was in **"maintenance mode"** (***php artisan down*** command) while we were doing updates and tests.

Comment: Yes, this was it for me too. Rather silly that it affects cron since it has nothing to do with the http level.

Comment: The solution is to bring the application out of maintenance mode by running `php artisan up`. The output will read `Application is now live.` if the application was in maintenance mode, or will read `Application is already up.` if maintenance mode was not active.

Answer (score 6):

The full answer to this question is not listed above as far as I can see.  Let's assume that our schedule is as follows:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule
        -> command('cbh:dummyCommand')
        -> everyFiveMinutes()
        -> appendOutputTo ('/my/logs/laravel_output.log');
}
```

What I've discovered is that this code doesn't set your job to run every 5 minutes.  Nor does it prevent the command running again if it was run less than 5-minutes ago.

A better way to think about it is that this code sets the named command *"to be runnable every time the minute-figure of the current time is `0` or `5`"*.  In other words, if I run the command-line argument: `php artisan schedule:run` at `11:04`, then the response is:

```bash
# No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

But if I run the same command at `11:00` or `11:05`, then we get:

```bash
# Running scheduled command: php artisan cbh:dummyCommand >> /my/logs/laravel_output.log 2>&1
```

And I end up with output in my log-file.

I discovered the above when my `everyFiveMinutes()` schedule was creating a log in my file every 10 minutes based on the fact that my task-scheduler was running every 2 minutes.

However, this doesn't quite address your issue, given that the `daily()` schedule (`0 0 * * *`) aligns with your cron-job schedule.  The only thing I can imagine is that there is some kind of misalignment with your time-zones as suggested by @Octavio Herrera.  But that's difficult to say without knowing a bit more about your environment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that my blog will help you answer your question. Please see the below or link: [Laravel Crontab](https://sonnguyen.ws/laravel-4-and-crontab/)
In many projects, you need use crontab (cron jobs) to execute some tasks as sending email or delete waste record in DB. With Laravel Project, you can do this easier.

Create a command in Laravel 4:

```
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
 
class FirstCommand extends Command {
 
        /**
         * The console command name.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $name = 'user:active';
 
        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Command description.';
 
        /**
         * Create a new command instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }
 
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function fire()
        {
                echo "User Actived";
        }
        /**
         * Get the console command arguments.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        protected function getArguments()
        {
                return array(
                );
        }
 
        /**
         * Get the console command options.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        protected function getOptions()
        {
                return array(
                        array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
                );
        }
 
}
```

Next step, you need to register the command with Laravel CLI. So easy, you open app/start/artisan.php file, and add one line as below:

```
Artisan::add(new FirstCommand);
```

You are done creating Laravel Command. To test, you could use command below:

```
$ php artisan user:active
```

User Active
The output above mean you successfully register a command.

Finally, put your command into the crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Add line (run command every 2 minutes):

```
*/2 * * * * php path_to_laravel_project/artisan user:active
```

That’s all. Thank you for talking time to read this.

Answer (score 2):

Try

**php artisan cache:clear**

and then run scheduler again with

**php artisan schedule:run**

I was also facing same issue and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I fixed this issue by setting the Scheduled Task to run **every minute** (even though I only wanted to trigger a command once per day), otherwise I always got the `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` message.

Answer (score 0):

Since I still ran into this issue 4 years later (2019) and a different workaround worked for me, I think it is worth hinting the simple step that solved for me, which is: Use a shorter interval first.

That seems to just wake it up to handle longer intervals in some ways. I had `everyFiveMinutes()` and for almost 2 hours it was getting the `No scheduled commands are ready to run` response. I simply changed it to `everyMinute()` and it started running correctly. I watched it consistently for like 10 minutes or so, then changed it back to `everyFiveMinutes()` and it all went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I've stuck with this problem `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` for an hours, but solve it easly:

Problem was with rights to folder **storage**.

So, i've set `chmod -R 777 storage/*` (i'm not sure is this is elegant way).

After that cron starts working properly.

Comment: Setting the permissions of the storage folder and its children to 777 is a really bad practice. Doing so will result in allowing everyone to upload, read and execute files on your server

Answer (score 0):

To run the Cron Commands on the ***local server***, follow these steps:

1. I know you have already mentioned the command in app/console/Kernel.php
2. Now open the command line, enter "crontab -e"
3. Edit that file and mention the below code(without quote) to keep running PHP artisan schedule:run in the background

> "* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"

4. Enter "crontab -l" in the command line, it will list running crons

Done !!

Now, wait for cron to process your command. Cheers!!

Reference- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason cron does not recognize the named version of your task.

So in your schedule instead of writing

**$schedule->command('command:task');**

you should use the path of the class, such as

**$schedule->command(\App\Console\Commands\TASK::class)**

...the same goes for the scheduler on Laravel Forge!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything but finally I found a solution for this problem. Add the timestamp in the command. Below is the example for this.

```
     $schedule->call(function(){
         print("HELLO");
     })->dailyAt('21:51')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');
```

or

```
$schedule->command('tenam:before')
        ->dailyAt('22:28')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');
```