# Laravel 5.3 Schedule Not working ( No scheduled commands are ready to run. )

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.3

The below is the schedule function

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('queue:work')
            ->everyMinute()
            ->withoutOverlapping();
    }
```

Below is the cron for laravel

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/space/public_html/project/artisan schedule:run >> /home/space/public_html/project/public/op.txt 2>&1
```

But each time the cron outputs

```
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

queue:work is not getting executed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: change this /home/space/public_html/project/public/op.txt to kernel of console directory

Comment: @MortezaNegahi But than that will override the kernel with the output of cron.. i used it to check the cron output.

Comment: In You'r queue:work class . append a Log::('Queue Done . some text'); and when Crone work ended . in your storage/log can see descriptions.

Comment: @MortezaNegahi well queue:work command is of the laravel, do you want me to log in the schedule function?

Comment: Are you in maintenance mode? Also (just to double check) if you run `php artisan queue:work` manually does it work?

Comment: @crazy1337 Look at this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552450/laravel-how-to-log-info-to-separate-file) and Do Ross Wilson comment

Comment: @RossWilson Yep! queue:work works. even the schedule function is called by the cron. but the thing is (i think) ->everyMinute() and other function is not getting recognized in order to run that on time..

Comment: @MortezaNegahi Hey when i remove ->withoutOverlapping() then it executes, but queue:work was not running as there were jobs in my queue pending, what might be the reason?

Comment: @MortezaNegahi Thanks for helping. Deleting all the schedule files in storage/framework did this job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting all the schedule files in storage/framework did this job.

The problem was the command was executed but was some error so never worked but the command was active preventing it to run again by the cron (because i used withoutOverlapping() ).