# Run Schedule Laravel with Command

Tags: php, laravel

I have command `SendEmails:send`, in the Kernel.

`$schedule->command('SendEmails:send')->everyMinute();`

But the scheduler doesn't work. However, if I run command...

```
php artisan SendEmails:send
```

All is OK. Lastly, if I run the command...

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

I get the message:

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel "No scheduled commands are ready to run."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700396/laravel-no-scheduled-commands-are-ready-to-run)

Comment: Possible Dublicate of [Laravel “No scheduled commands are ready to run.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700396/laravel-no-scheduled-commands-are-ready-to-run)

Comment: How's your cronjob set up? Does it run other scheduled commands?

Comment: @kerbholz Why is cronjob? If test dont work cron work perfectly.
I run command php artisan SendEmails:send all ok
php artisan schedule:run - dont work

Comment: A cronjob, to run your scheduled commands: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling